# MVC com PHP e BOOTSTRAP

Tags: php, mvc

Estou iniciando os estudos em MVC. atualmente uso o PHP para isso.
tenho uma rotina pequena de paginação de uma plataforma de cursos. ela utiliza o php.
link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iz_JkRRBFWxzQIi-wM30dE7D0fIJTrST/view?usp=sharing

porem quando rodo o projeto, as funções nao funcionam. os links parecem não existir, nem os arquivos de estilização são carregados. 
uso o xampp e descompacto o projeto dentro do htdocs.

qual configuração devo realizar?
muito obrigado pelo auxilio.

Comment: Resolvendo o problema. há um arquivo encontrado na pasta app. seu método construtor ja carrega todas as constantes usadas em todo o projeto. ,..
como as de conexões com o banco e inclusive a que recebe o host. só é necessário alterar o valor da constante host para o nome da pasta onde o projeto esta inserido. att